# How to pass container components into react-router-dom Route?

Tags: react-router-v4, react-router-redux, react-router-dom

I'm currently having typescript issue with passing the correct type in react router redux.

typescript-error:

```
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Type '{ path: "/foo/:id"; component: typeof "<path>..' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Rea...'.
      Type '{ path: "/foo/:id"; component: typeof "<path>..'  is not assignable to type 'Readonly<RouteProps>'.
        Types of property 'component' are incompatible.
          Type 'typeof "<path>..'  is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<RouteComponentProps<any>> | ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any>>'.
            Type 'typeof "<path>..'  is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any>>'.
              Type 'typeof "<path>..'  provides no match for the signature 'new (props?: RouteComponentProps<any>, context?: any): Component<RouteComponentProps<any>, ComponentState>'.'
```

This seems to be happening because I'm passing a container component into the `<Route... />`.  However, it's not clear to me why this wouldn't work because mapsToProps should be returning a RouteComponentProps.

Foo.ts (Component):

```
export interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
    a: string;
}

export class Foo extends React.Component<Props, void> {
    public render() {
        //code
    }
}
```

FooContainer.ts:

```
function mapStateToProps(state: State, ownProps: Props): Props {
    const mappedProps: Props = {
        foo: "super"
    };

    return mappedProps;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Foo);
```

routes:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import FooContainer from "./FooContainer";
export const routes = (
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/foo/:id" component={FooContainer} />
    </Switch>
);
```

nom libraries/version:

```
 "@types/react": "^16.0.5",
 "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.4",
 "@types/react-redux": "4.4.40",
 "@types/react-router-dom": "4.0.7",
 "@types/react-router-redux": "5.0.8",
 "react": "^15.6.1",
 "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
 "react-redux": "5.0.4",
 "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
 "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.6",
```

If you look at my Props, it extends RouteComponentProps which is:

```
export interface RouteComponentProps<P> {
  match: match<P>;
  location: H.Location;
  history: H.History;
}
```

If that is true, shouldn't mapStateToProps contain the match?

Answer (score 0):

So I got around the problem with :

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(foo) as React.ComponentClass<any>;
```

Not sure why I need to specify the return type with React.ComponentClass.  Isn't it implicit?